# Remove Border From Select Dropdown

Tags: css, select, html-select

Is there any idea, how to remove orange border from select option list, please see the attached screen shot[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: share some coding...

Answer (score 0):

Give the following css class to your dropdown:

```
.ddlBooks
{
     border:none !important;
}
```